# One-time pad solution incorrect

Tags: encryption

```
A one time pad encryption system represents the letters A-E with numbers 1-5 and a space with the number 0. Given the cipher text: DBCA

and the one time pad: BCBC

What is the encrypted word?
```

**My solution:**

A B C D E _
1 2 3 4 5 0

**Cipher text:** DBCA
**One-time pad & key:** BCBC

B C B C
2 3 2 3

D B C A 
4 2 3 1

**Encrypted text:**
B A A B
2 1 1 2

The encrypted word I got is: BAAB which isn't a word so I'm so it's incorrect

I've researched how to use one-time pad but I still don't understand it

Comment: A one-time pad works on bits using the XOR operation. Surely we can represent the numbers 0-5 as bits, but XORing B and D (2 and 4) would result in 6 which is not in the range of 0-5. What is supposed to happen with numbers that are not in the range? Also, why do you think that your solution is wrong?

Comment: I tried multiple times and sometimes I got 6 too and 8 as well but that's not in the range and nothing is said about numbers that are out of the range. I only think my solution is wrong because it's meant to be an encrypted word and BAAB isn't a word. Does the result have to be an ACTUAL word?

Comment: *"Does the result have to be an ACTUAL word?"* - No idea, ask your instructor.

Answer (score 0):

One-time pad is not like that.
your code length must be at least as long as your text. Since you are going to use it one time for each encrypting and decrypting your text.

```
f = open("plain.txt", "rb+")
kf = open ("key.txt", "rb" )
f2= open("cipher.txt", "r+")

allplain = f.read()
key =[]
key = kf.read()
#   - encrypt plain text and save into cipher.txt

for i in range(len(allplain)):
    k = chr (key[i])
    p = chr (allplain[i])
    c = chr ((ord(p)) ^ (ord(k)))
    f2.write(c)
```

this is a complete implementation of One-Time Pad encryption in Python.
[One-Time Pad Encryption](https://shooreshsufiye.blogspot.se/2017/11/one-time-pad-encryption-in-python.html)